# How to define a flag inside the Component Template?

Tags: angular

I have this iteration:

```
    <div class="resultsCtn clearfix" *ngFor="let result of results;let i = index">

      <!-- this index should be rendered just if at least one of the results happen and only one time for iteration!!! -->
      <h5 *ngIf="some_flag"><span class="numberCircle">{{ i+1 }}</span></h5> 

      <!-- option_one -->
      <h5 *ngIf="result.option_one" class="optionsStyle">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hasFixed;"></ng-container>
        {{ result.option_one }}
      </h5>

      <!-- option_two -->
      <h5 *ngIf="result.option_two" class="optionsStyle">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hasFixed;"></ng-container>
        {{ result.option_two }}
      </h5>

      <!-- option_three -->
      <h5 *ngIf="result.option_three" class="optionsStyle">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hasFixed;"></ng-container>
        {{ result.option_three }}
      </h5>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to render the `<h5 *ngIf="some_flag"><span class="numberCircle">{{ i+1 }}</span></h5>` just if one of the options has instancing.

the problem: I don't want to create another function to check if the data is ok since I have many params to check (and they're already renderd if they exists.

So, I just want a **flag** inside the options `div`s that changed to true.
(or any better idea without creating new function)

Comment: Then you can use: `<h5 *ngIf="results.length"><span class="numberCircle">{{ i+1 }}</span></h5>`

Comment: No, not all the result are ok. there is different types that I ignore

Comment: if are a few you can *ngIf="result.option_one || result.option_two || result.option_three", or put the *ngIf="result.option" in a ng-container and inside ng-container the span and the h5

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I can't do that.. there is more that 100 options.. I can't check everyone. I prefer to put inside a flag that check if something is already rendered so it will not render it again